# Apply for India visa but not effective immediately

Tags: visas, india

As Canadian national applying for a visa for India, I have a problem. I wish to visit in India, but I want to make the application now since I will get very busy in coming months. If I apply now, I will be granted a 6 month visa effective immediately and will expire before my journey date.
In the application, is there a way to mention that I do not want visa effective immediately?

Answer (score 4):

No, the Toronto consulate's FAQ specificially addresses this:

> **I will travel at a much later date. Can my visa be issued to coincide
> with the date of travel?**
>
> No. Post - dated visas are not issued. The
> validity of the visa begins from the date of issue.

http://www.cgitoronto.ca/Visa/visaFAQ.html